# Jekyll with CloudFlare https causing too many redirects

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages, cloudflare

I am running a website with Jekyll inside github pages with CloudFlare CDN and HTTPS on top off it.

At CloudFlare I enable the **"Always use HTTPS"** for my domain with the rule: `http://*example.com/*`

The problem occurs when the address typed does not contains the end slash, ie: `https://www.example.com/my-permalink`

As the nature of Jekyll, it generates the file: `/my-permalink/index.html`, so when address does not contains the "/" at the ends, it puts it, so user can access the index.html file inside the directory. Its not a big deal...

The **expected** behavior should be done in TWO steps:

- User enter: `https://www.example.com/my-permalink`
- It is redirected to: `https://www.example.com/my-permalink/`, witch is `index.html` behind the scenes.

But in the actual behavior, it is loosing the HTTPS protocol in the first redirect, then redirect again with the https protocol, all done in 3 steps:

- User enter: `https://www.example.com/my-permalink`
- It is redirected to (Without HTTPS): `http://www.example.com/my-permalink/`
- Then it is redirected to: `https://www.example.com/my-permalink/`

This is what is happening now according to PageSpeed:

[image]

So, how can I prevent the incorrect "http" redirect to have the expected behavior (redirect in 2 steps)?

Comment: Can you give a real url to test for redirections ?

Comment: `https://www.maosdeamar.com.br/doula` you will probably can see the redirect problem on your browser just once, then you can see at [pagespeed insights] (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maosdeamar.com.br%2Fdoula).